# Multitasking Menu in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

**Multitasking Menu in Shell Script**

I have a Shell Script ( test.sh ) to do 4 tasks within a menu. The tasks are to clean terminal history, downloads folder, trash can, or exit. The code I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

function menu {
clear
echo "[1] Clean Terminal"
echo ""
echo "[2] Clean Downloads"
echo ""
echo "[3] Clean Trash"
echo ""
echo "[x] Exit"
echo ""

read -p "Option > " option

}

function terminal {
    clear
    cd
    cat /dev/null > .bash_history
    echo "Terminal history is now cleared!"
}

function downloads {
     clear
     cd
     rm -r Downloads/*
     echo "Downloads directory is now cleared!"
}

function trash {
     clear
     cd
     rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
     echo "Trash is now cleared!"
}

function terminate {
     exit
}

end_script=0
while [ "${end_script}" != 1 ];do
    menu
    case ${option} in
    1)
        terminal
    ;;

    2)
        downloads
    ;;

    3)
        trash
    ;;


    x)

        terminate
    ;;

    *)
        clear
        echo "unknown usage!"
    ;;
    esac
done
```

**What the Executed Script looks like:**

```
[1] Clean Terminal

[2] Clean Downloads

[3] Clean Trash

[x] Exit

Option >
```

**What the Problem is:**

The problem I am having, is that this menu is only accepting single input from the user (Only able to put 1 number at a time). What I would like it to be able to do is input multiple inputs and just divide them like this (1, 2) or (1 2 3).

**What I've Tried So Far...**

I've brainstormed a while about this one. One way I thought of doing this was to create individual functions for all variations of numbers and add the code, but this would be extremely time consuming for larger menus, and it doesn't seem very logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse user input, loop through every entered option and
check `case` in every iteration. Check this simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Option > " option
for i in $option; do echo an option: $i; done
```

Usage:

```
$ ./ex.sh
Option > 1 2 3
an option: 1
an option: 2
an option: 3
```

So your whole script would be like this (I added a few debug messages and
`sleep` lines):

```
#!/bin/bash

function menu {
clear
echo "[1] Clean Terminal"
echo ""
echo "[2] Clean Downloads"
echo ""
echo "[3] Clean Trash"
echo ""
echo "[x] Exit"
echo ""

read -p "Option > " option

}

function terminal {
    clear
    cd
    cat /dev/null > .bash_history
    echo "Terminal history is now cleared!"
    sleep 5
}

function downloads {
     clear
     cd
     rm -r Downloads/*
     echo "Downloads directory is now cleared!"
     sleep 5
}

function trash {
     clear
     cd
     rm -rf ~/.local/share/Trash/*
     echo "Trash is now cleared!"
     sleep 5
}

function terminate {
     exit
}

end_script=0
while [ "${end_script}" != 1 ];do
    menu
    echo ADDED BY ME: option is $option
    sleep 5
    for i in $option
    do
    echo ADDED BY ME: current option is $i
    case ${i} in
        1)
        terminal
        ;;

        2)
        downloads
        ;;

        3)
        trash
        ;;
        x)

        terminate
        ;;

        *)
        clear
        echo "unknown usage!"
        ;;
    esac
    done
done
```

Comment: Thank you @Arkadiusz , I knew there was a simple solution out there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  read -p "Option > " options
  for option in ${options//,/ }; do   # replace all , by white spaces
   case ${option} in
    1) echo "function terminal";;
    2) echo "function downloads";;
    3) echo "function trash";;
    x) echo "terminate"; exit;;
    *) echo "unknown usage!";;
    esac
  done
done
```

Example usage at read's prompt: `5,3, 2 1  x`

Output:

```
unknown usage!
function trash
function downloads
function terminal
terminate
```